# How can I write info to sitin.txt in terminal using "cat > " and then it will output

Tags: c

I'm new to C++ (Started today and only did for about 10 minutes). How can I compile and run on terminal? It is a basic program which calculates the number of seats available(r*s). First input line is to be the number of rows and seats, second input line will be number of tickets (people attending). Then output will show how many people are sitting and then standing respectively.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        int r, s, sit,stand,tickets;
    freopen("sitin.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("sitout.txt", "w", stdout);
    scanf("%d %d", &r, &s);
    scanf("%d", &tickets); 
    printf("%d %d\n",r*s,tickets-(r*s));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when writing code, for ease of understanding and readability by us humans, 1) please consistently indent the code.  never use tabs for indenting as each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and allows many indent levels across the page.  2) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) 1 variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: suggest using paper and pencil and see what the results should be when less tickets sold than available seats and when tickets sold = available seats and when tickets sold is greater than available seats.  Then write your code to properly output the right numbers regardless of which condition is true.  Note: the final call to `printf()` does not display the correct values for any of the input conditions

Comment: in general, 1 or 2 letter variable names are meaningless.  Always use variable names that have meaning within the context of the code.   for instance use `rows` rather than `r` and use `seatsPerRow` rather than `s`.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (I also use: `-Wconversion -std=c99`) ).   Which ever compiler/linker you use, read the associated documentation and look on-line for examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile C code in Unix/Linux environment you can use GCC (Gnu C Compiler):

```
 gcc srcfile.c -o exefile
```

Where `srcfile.c` is name of your file with source code.
If you do not use `-o` option, gcc will make executable (binary) file with name `a.out`.

See more options by running `gcc --h` or `man gcc`

**EDIT:**

Perhaps, the following information will be useful for you.

If you create code

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    int r, s, sit,stand,tickets;
    scanf("%d %d", &r, &s);
    scanf("%d", &tickets); 
    printf("%d %d\n",r*s,tickets-(r*s));
    return 0;
}
```

save it to file `code.c` compile it as

```
  gcc code.c
```

and run as

```
  ./a.out <sitin.txt >sitout.txt
```

your program (`a.out`) will take inputs for `scanf` function from `sitin.txt` (file have to be available for reading) and put output from `printf` function to `sitout.txt` (file will be created)

Comment: In Terminal: 
gcc -o test  test.cpp -Wall
 ./test

Those are my two lines in terminal. 
How can I input using cat > ?

Comment: to make input from a file use `./test < file.txt` in that case you do not need to use `reopen` in the code

Answer (score 2):

with the gcc compiler/linker use:

```
gcc -g -c myfile.c -o myfile.o -I.
```

to compile `myfile.c` to produce the object file `myfile.o`

then use:

```
gcc -g myfile.o -o myfile
```

to link the file `myfile.o` to produce the executable `myfile`

then execute it using

```
cat sitin.txt | ./myfile > sitout.txt
```

the above line does: 1) invoke the `cat` utility, passing it the `sitin.txt` file as a parameter.  2) redirect the `stdout` of `cat` to `stdin` of myfile.  3) the `stdout` of myfile is redirected to the `sitout.txt` file

Do not change the initial file pointers for `stdin` and stdout`if going to use`cat`and`redirection` as your question indicates.

Answer (score 0):

It is a purely C style coding so we request you to kindly edit the tag from c++ to c.

Secondly, for compiling and running in a single command on linux terminal use

```
gcc -g -Wall <program_name.c> -o <binary name>
```

Then for running the binary use the following command:

```
 ./<binary name>
```

---

**Second Method** is first create .o file by using only compilation

```
gcc -g -Wall -c <program_name.c>
```

Then use linking as

```
gcc <program_name.o> -o <binary name>
```

now, u can run the binary as

```
   ./binary name
```

Comment: I'm still confused, it's not working. How do I enter my input? (I'm legitimately completely new).

Comment: Can you please specify whether it is a .c or .cpp file ?